# Setting QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS fails

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, plugins, qt5

I have read this blogpost http://www.ics.com/blog/qt-tips-and-tricks-part-1 and tried to enable plugin debugging as described.

I've put this line in my main.cpp:

<s>qputenv(QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS, 1);</s>

But if I try to compile I'm getting this error:

```
.../src/main.cpp:14: error: 'QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS' was not declared in this scope
qputenv(QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS, -1);
```

What is the problem here and how do I have to do it right?

```
qputenv("QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS", QByteArray("1"));
```

But I don't get any additional output.

I'm using Qt5.5.1 with QtCreator 3.6 under KUbuntu 15.10.

Comment: Possible problems in your qputenv: put quotes around QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS and the second type in qputenv is QByteArray. There is no constructor of a QByteArray from an int.

Comment: That was the problem. Now it compiles. Thank you. But I won't get any additional output.

Comment: You're supposed to set env variable from *outside* your program, not from inside! It's very likely the plugin loading you're interested into already happened by the time you reach that line. Try putting it before creating a `Q*Application` object.

Comment: That's it. It was definitely set before plugin loading, but it seems to be important to set it before creating `Q*Application` as you wrote. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You're supposed to set env variable from *outside* your program, not from inside! It's very likely the plugin loading you're interested into already happened by the time you reach that line. Try putting it before creating a `Q*Application` object.
                    – peppe

That's it. It was definitely set before plugin loading, but it seems to be important to set it before creating `Q*Application` as you wrote. Thank you.
                    – avb